# Mutating data through API

Tags: javascript, json, graphql, monday.com

I am using Zapier to create a Monday.com task every time a new lead is created in Copper (my CRM). The problem is that Zapier only allows the information to stored in the task name on Monday.com. I have created a webhook that is supposed to parse the needed data out of the Monday.com task title and update the column values as needed. However, my code is currently not doing that. I am receiving no errors when I create a task yet the columns are not populating properly. I am not sure what is the issue.

Here is the code:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

const updateMultipleColumnValues = require("./updateMultipleColumnValue").updateMultipleColumnValue;

const app = express();

  app.use( bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');



  app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    const { boardId, pulseId } = req.body.event

      let parsedRecord = extractData(req.body.event.pulseName)
      console.log(parsedRecord);

      let newData = {
        "text0": parsedRecord.DURATION
      };

      let stringData = JSON.stringify(newData);

      console.log(boardId);
      console.log(pulseId);
      console.log(stringData);
      updateMultipleColumnValues(boardId, pulseId, stringData);
    res.json(parsedRecord);
  });

  app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`));





// console.log(extractData(targetStr, fields));

function extractData(str) {
  let fields = ['DATE', 'TIME', 'DURATION', 'TYPE'];

  return str.split(/\s*\|\s*/).reduce((res, entry) => {
    let dat = entry.split(/\s*:\s*/);
    return fields.indexOf(dat[0]) > -1 ? Object.assign(res, { [dat[0]]: dat[1] }) : res;
  }, {});
}
```

Here is the updateMultipleColumnValue file:

```
const executeMondayQuery = require("./executeMondayQuery").executeMondayQuery;

const updateMultipleColumnValue = async (boardId, itemId, newData) => {
  const updateColumnValueBody = {
    query: `mutation {
                change_multiple_column_values(
                board_id: ${boardId},
                item_id: ${itemId},
                column_values: ${newData}
                ) { id }
            }`
  };

  await executeMondayQuery(updateColumnValueBody);
};

exports.updateMultipleColumnValue = updateMultipleColumnValue;
```

Monday.com use graphQL

Answer (score 2):

Edit: We'll release a new Copper integration next week, so if you don't want to go through the trouble of recreating it with Zapier, you can wait for this release.

Anyway, there are a two things you probably need to address in this implementation.

#### TL;DR Solution

You need to escape your string before sending it in the mutation. This should work:

```
const updateColumnValueBody = {
    query: `mutation {
                change_multiple_column_values(
                board_id: ${boardId},
                item_id: ${itemId},
                column_values: "${newData.replace(/"/g, '\\"')}"
                ) { id }
            }`
  };
```

---

#### A word about GraphQL error handling

I'm not sure what's the logic inside the `executeMondayQuery` function, but if a parsing error occurred during the execution of a GraphQL mutation, the HTTP response itself still has a 200 status code.

The body of the response will contain an `errors` array describing all syntax errors in the payload.

#### Escaping strings in GraphQL JSON attributes

In this specific case the issue is probably that your `newData` (originally `stringData`) isn't escaped, and isn't wrapped in double quotes (indicating it's a string).

What happens is that after string interpolation your payload looks like so:

```
mutation {
  change_multiple_column_values(
    board_id: 12345678,
    item_id: 87654321,
    column_values: {"text": "123"}
  ) { id }
}
```

But the `column_values` attribute of `change_multiple_column_values` accepts a JSON formatted *string*

So what you actually want is:

```
mutation {
  change_multiple_column_values(
    board_id: 12345678,
    item_id: 87654321,
    column_values: "{\"text\": \"123\"}"
  ) { id }
}
```